# How to set-up or confirm email account to sent email from my send mail application in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, email

How to set-up or confirm email account to sent email from my send mail application in Windows Phone 7

I created simple email sending application in Windows Phone 7 but when i click on Send button i got this message:- 
"`Make sure you've set-up an account and try again`"

this is my application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
namespace SendingMail
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        EmailAddressChooserTask emailAddresstask;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.emailAddresstask = new EmailAddressChooserTask();
            this.emailAddresstask.Completed += new EventHandler<EmailResult>(emailAddresstask_Completed);
        }
        #region Events

        //Open Contact button click
        private void btnOpenContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            emailAddresstask.Show();
        }

        //Email Address Chooser Task Completed
        private void emailAddresstask_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                txtTo.Text = e.Email;
            }
        }

        //Send mail button click
        private void btnMail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EmailComposeTask Myemail_Composetask = new EmailComposeTask();
            Myemail_Composetask.To = txtTo.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Cc = txtCC.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Subject = txtSbj.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Body = txtbd.Text;
            Myemail_Composetask.Show();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up an email account in the Windows Phone 7 emulator. You'll need to test this on a Windows Phone 7 device, or else use the Windows Phone 8 SDK and the Windows Phone 8 emulator to test this scenario for your Windows Phone 7 app.

From a device or the Windows Phone 8 emulator, go to Settings and select "email+accounts" and add the account.

Comment: Can i provide login for my application just like facebook app.

Comment: No you can't as you are accessing functionality which is part of the phone OS. The Facebook app is doing it's own thing using the SDK functionality.